# WebGL error - "glDrawArrays: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 0"

Tags: javascript, webgl, vertex

### Edit:

After grueling reviewal of the code I happened to make the right alteration to have this triangle render.  In the code posted here, the vertices and colors Arrays are declared before `initBuffers`.  In my actual code, they are declared somewhat after.  Because javascript (in sublime text) was auto-completing these variables no matter where I defined them (like methods in a java class, say..) and because chrome was throwing no errors, I assumed this could not be the problem.  Yet simply shifting these array initializations from after `initShaders`, `initBuffers` to before those calls was the crux of my problem.  I'm sorry for posting a fundamental unanswerable question but hopefully this will serve as a helpful warning to future people that declaration time matters with regards to webGL buffers.  More rigorous checking of shader compilation/linking may yield better information here.

///////////////////

I'm taking some WebGL code I found in a tutorial and trying to refactor it to use code-specified color values for each vertex.  Unfortunately, after working this code it, I receive the aforementioned "out of range" error.

node - any not seen declarations are global vars

I have the following setup code, initializing buffers:

The vertex information is specified like so:

```
var vertices = [
        0.0,  1.0,
        -1.0, -1.0,
         1.0, -1.0
];


var colors = [

    1, 0, 0,
    1, 0, 0,
    1, 0, 0

];




var gl;

var shaderProgram;


var triangleVertexPositionBuffer;
var triangleVertexColorBuffer;


var canvas = document.getElementById("ABID");
gl = canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
gl.viewportWidth = canvas.width;
gl.viewportHeight = canvas.height;



function initBuffers() {

    triangleVertexPositionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleVertexPositionBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    triangleVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize = 2;



    triangleVertexColorBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleVertexColorBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(colors), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    triangleVertexColorBuffer.itemSize = 3;


}


initBuffers();
```

Then creating my shaders/program where I try to get attribute locations and set them on the global variable, 'shaderProgram':

```
function initShaders() {

    var fragmentShader = getShader(gl, "shader-fs");
    var vertexShader = getShader(gl, "shader-vs");

    shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
    gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);

    if (!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
        alert("Could not initialise shaders");
    }

    gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);

    shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexPosition");
    shaderProgram.vertexColorAttrib = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexColor");

    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexColorAttrib);


}
```

It depends on a getShader function which works perfectly.  The shaders are as follows:

```
<script id="shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    precision mediump float;

    varying vec3 color;

    void main(void) {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(1,0,0, 1);
    }
</script>

<script id="shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
    attribute vec2 aVertexPosition;
    attribute vec3 aVertexColor;



    varying vec3 color;

    void main(void) {
        gl_Position = vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0,1.0);
        color = aVertexColor;
    }
</script>
```

And finally, the error occurs somehow when drawing these 3 vertices:

```
draw();

function draw() {

    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.viewportWidth, gl.viewportHeight);
    gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);



    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleVertexPositionBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute, triangleVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);


    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleVertexColorBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexColorAttrib, triangleVertexColorBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);


    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);


}
```

I'm sure there is some offset, or size or magic number typed incorrectly but I've been over this many times and cannot spot the error.  Being an openGL beginner and a lack of debugging insights compounds the frustrations.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try changing your colors to `var colors = [
    1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 0.0, 0.0

];` arrays and generics dont usually mix well. This could be the issue.

Comment: [Try some different tutorials](http://webglfundamentals.org)?

Comment: I'm glad you found the error. Just FYI, this is not special to WebGL buffers. You used the arrays before you put data in them. That's no different than `console.log(a); var a = 12;` which will print `undefined`.

Comment: i'm coming from writing openGL in c where attempting to do anything with an undefined value is a compilation error.  so this oversight really elluded me.

Comment: also the webGL error of  "drawing out of range" would have been better as "drawing no range" or something if undefined vertex data was the issue

Comment: Only problem with that is the additional checking it has to do each time its run. The bounds checking adds an expense already, and with graphics you want it to be as fast as possible. I agree figuring these things out with webgl can be a little cryptic. Errors like this though can be helped by using eslint :)